# restore files from backup directory recursively

Tags: backup, restore

i backuped hundreds of files from `source directory` using script, files in my `backup directory` have the same names, also `backup directory`'s **directory structure** is also same as `source directory`

how can i restore all files from my `backup directory` back to the `source directory`? thanks!

also, i've tried `rsync`

```
rsync -avP /path/to/backup/ /path/to/source
rsync -aAXv /path/to/backup/ /path/to/source
rsync -aAXv --delete /path/to/backup/ /path/to/source
```

after that, i can see in vscode, there're more changes ...

Comment: Am I missing something or will a simple [rsync](https://averagelinuxuser.com/backup-and-restore-your-linux-system-with-rsync/) do what you need?

Comment: @BrianZ, i googled a bit and did found post of using rsync, i'm not sure if i did something wrong, it didn't work for me:

rsync -avP /path/to/backup/ /path/to/source

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific. **How** did this `rsync` command not work for you?

Comment: @berndbausch, this might be an issue before i restore ...

i was using `sed -i.bak` to apply mass change in source, then move all those `.bak` files to my backup dir

in vscode, i can see there were 300+ changes, when i restore from back, there's 1k+ changes, including new files

Comment: i found the problem, i need to add `/` at end of the backup dir, without that slash, it would create a backup folder in source dir